# runtime.lastError, Chrome extension manifest permission problem

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I did check other topics both here and Google but did NOT find any solutions. I'm a newbie so a small explanation will be greatly appreciated. This is the error I get using this code:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.

I checked all the permissions but nothing seems to work. And the main problem is that the code does not inject on the page itself, when I use console of my extension, that error appears there not in my let's say Google.com webpage's console. What am I doing wrong?

Manifest.json

```
{"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Change Color",
"description": "Pretty much just a test extension",
"version": "0.1",
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"permissions": [
        "activeTab"
]
},
"content_scripts": [
{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["popup.js"]
}]}
```

For popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>

    <div> Enable/Disable </div> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="xxx" />

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for popup.js

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

          document.getElementById("xxx").addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (this.checked) {
             chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
            code : 'console.log("ON")'
        });
            } else {
              chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{
            code : 'console.log("OFF")'
            });
            }
          });
        });
```

Comment: 1) Move `permissions` out of `browser_action` block and use an editor that can autoformat/autocheck JS and JSON. 2) Remove `content_scripts` section from manifest.json. It automatically injects the specified script into web pages but this script is only for the popup page which is an extension page, not a web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are my hero! I can't believe how stupid were my mistakes... I didn't pay any attention to the browser_action section. Thank you!